# Any other text editor can edit the UTF8 text (like "\u7F51\u7BA1\u7CFB" in those *.perpertis file) created by netbeans

Tags: text, netbeans, utf-8, editor

Guys,

I am looking for a text editor or method to deal with the UTF8 encoded *.properties file created by the Netbeans (6.x and 7.0.x). Trust me I have tried Notepad++, PsPad, gVim, jedit, etc without luck. Or I have just missed somehing?

The items is in the form of followings:

update.text=\u4FEE\u6539

The reason for this is I am trying to use script to modify some property items during the build process.

At the moment only Netbeans itself can read and display the content correctly. Any ideas?

Thanks.

David

Answer (score 0):

I use [WinVi](http://www.winvi.de/), which supports UTF-8, UTF-16, and hex/binary editing.

Comment: Thanks, Remy, I tried WinVi, it editing behavior is just like the Windows version of VIM. Still it was not able to display "\u4FEE\u6539" as two UTF-8 Chinese characters in "update.text=\u4FEE\u6539", just as the editors I mentioned before. In Netbeans, it displays as "update.text=XX", where X is a single Chinese characters.

Comment: If the text in the file actually consists of literals like "\u4FEE", meaning a slash character followed by 5 ASCII characters, then no text editor (that I know of) is going to interpret that as Unicode, it is going to display the ASCII data as-is, just as you have seen. The original Unicode data has been escaped into an ASCII-compatible format when saved into the file. Only Netbeans knows the data is escaped and knows how to unescape it back to the original Unicode data. You would likely have to write your own text editor that parses and unescapes the file data before displaying it.

Comment: Thanks again Remy, seems the only way to do is to stick with netbeans for a while， at least for the current project.